# Passing an array through a function fills it with zeroes

Tags: arrays, c

```
void print_array(int *array, int n)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int *array[] = {20,30,55,87,38,91,7,78};

    print_array(array, 8);

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[j]);
    }
}
```

I encountered a problem in my code and stripped it down to what you see above while trying to troubleshoot it.
When I print the array from outside the function print_array, it works fine.
However, when I print the array from within the function, a zero appears between every element in the array.
For example, for an array {20,30,55,87,38,91,7,78}, the program will print {20,0,30,0,55,0,87,0,38,0,91,0,7,0,78,0}
I've never encountered this problem before. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps use `int **array` as the type for the `print_array` parameter, otherwise the pointer type is incompatible.

Comment: Notice the difference between your array declaration `int *array[]` and the function `print_array(int *array, int n)`. You probably meant to declare your array like `int array[] = ...`

Comment: That would be the problem... I wonder why it created such a weird error though?

Comment: Because a pointer is 8 bytes and an int is 4 bytes. The difference in type inside main and the function means the pointer math used while indexing is different.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int array[] = {20,30,55,87,38,91,7,78}; // Change this line

    print_array(array, 8);

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[j]);
    }
}
```

This error occurs because the `array` variable was an array of pointers to `int`, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

`int *array[] = {20,30,55,87,38,91,7,78};` is incorrrect code. A non-zero integer cannot be used to initialize a pointer.

If you didn't get a compiler error message then the first thing you must do is change your compiler settings so that to produce an error message for this code.

The rest of your problems stem from trying to run erroneous code; you have wasted a lot of time through not invoking the compiler properly.

*NB. This is very important. I wrote it as an answer, as 95% of the time when I comment to this effect, the OP ignores the comment and continues to struggle with downstream effects of having the erroneous code.*

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `int *array[]` instead of `int array[]`, that's the only error.
I don't know what compiler you are using but you should enable warnings. If there is one or more warnings, your exe will be created but you will never know about warnings such as:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
```

Now it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int *array, int n){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%d ", array[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    int array[] = {20,30,55,87,38,91,7,78};
    print_array(array, 8);
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        printf("%d ", array[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```